# how to call out again the functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reset

I watched the JavaScript tutorial of cleverprogrammer at youtube then I saw his rock, paper, scissors game. I thought of an idea to add some function in his game that will reset or will move onto next round. But when I try the `remove()` or `document.getElementById('id name of my form').remove()`, it will clear what is in the frontend but I don't know some command that will show the game again and when I used the `reset()` is showing some error: `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).reset is not a function`.

The program:

[rock, paper, scissor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gV05.jpg)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KzFE.jpg)

is there some other way or command that will show the game again?

Comment: You're mixing up the things. use jQuery or JS functions separately. I would recommend you to use jQuery as you're talking about remove/reset etc.

Comment: so jQuery can do that. thank you for telling me

Comment: You can show your code here for better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reset()` method resets the values of all elements in a form. At `W3school`, You can read in detail about [reset](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) property. But if you want to get the removed element back again, For this you can use the `"detach"` property.

For more info, check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_detach.asp